# Hiding specific option elements from iOS select list via CSS or Script

Tags: jquery, ios, css, responsive-design, navigation

I have a web application in which a select list is dynamically generated via javascript. The select is taken from a pre-existing menu list in the DOM.

I have just found that iOS ignores CSS targeted at select lists. For example, I have a media query at max-width:768 that is designed to hide a specific item within the select list from view when the screen size is 768px and lower.

Although this appears to work as expected using device emulation tools (ie, quirktools/screenfly), the display:none rule is completely ignored when the select list is displayed on an actual iOS device.

Is there a suggested workaround?

Comment: You could make multiple `select` elements and toggle the visibility of the whole thing in the media query.

Comment: Can jQuery conditionals be wrapped in the equivalent of media queries? ie, if (screen.max-width <= 768px) {create menu item; }

Comment: They can, you can evaluate `$(window).width()` or something similar, but in order to make this evaluation you'll incur performance issues as it'll need to be bound to the window resize event. Of course, you can throttle this, but I'd personally prefer to take a hit on the duplicate markup and remove any need to use event handlers. It depends on the context of your problem though. I didn't know this was the case with selects btw, nice catch, +1.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I decided to go with here is to introduce a conditional in the jQuery to prevent it from being written to the option list.

Because the select is only displayed on < 768px devices anyway, there is no need to involve the media query or window.width.

As a result, the menu item never gets written to the select list, and iOS select CSS overrides do not pose an issue.

```
$("nav.main li a").each(function () {

    var el = $(this);
    var elt = el.text();

    // Removing the extra » symbol
    elt = elt.replace("»", "");
    if (elt != 'Hide This Menu Item') {
        //Continue building select option list
    }
}
```